# Create an id autoincrement with dapper

Tags: c#, sql, .net, dapper

I'm working with Dapper and .Net 6.0... I have to do an insert from table1 to table2... in the insert the columns match each other... the only column is "toID" of table1... which does NOT match the column of table2 (that's why I put a **4** in it) but I have to make it auto-increment so that for each insert there is an incrementing sequence

```
var sql =
            $"INSERT INTO table1 (toId,teId,dateShift,SectorOrigen) SELECT  4,teID,@dateModify,@LastSector FROM table2";
```

That is to say... that when I generate an insert the ID = 1, then another ID = 2 and so on continuously

Any advice??

Comment: Advice? Let the database handle the auto-generation of ID values ...

Comment: Really silly question because it works perfectly .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can create and use the sequence https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on this site. You could add an example code snippet demonstrating usage of the syntax in a way that is relevant to the asker's needs.